# pyspark change data capture implementation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, change-data-capture

I have one base table, which is holding the actual data. below is the table structure

| id | name | address | age | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | {"fname": "Alex", "lname": "Bhatt"} | {"lane": "Mac Street", "flat": ["24", "26", "27", "29"]} | 56 | 20201128 |
| A2 | {"fname": "Bob", "lname": "Natarajan"} | {"lane": "Royd Street", "flat": ["22", "23", "27"], "pin": "123514"} | 53 | 20201123 |
| A1 | {"fname": "Alex", "lname": "Bhattacharya"} | {"lane": "Mac Street", "flat": ["24", "26", "27", "29"]} | 56 | 20201228 |
| A2 | {"fname": "Bob", "lname": "Natarajan"} | {"lane": "Royd Street", "flat": ["22", "24", "27"], "pin": "123514"} | 53 | 20201228 |

In the above table for A1 and A2 there is change in data. This changed data summary is captured and provided by another table. The table structure is mentioned below.

| id | changed_field | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | name.lname | 20201228 |
| A2 | address.flat[1] | 20201228 |

From the above 2 table, I have to prepare the final table where the detail of changed data will be captured. Below is the expected table.

| id | changed_field | new_value | newdate | old_value | olddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | name.lname | Bhattacharya | 20201228 | Bhatt | 20201128 |
| A2 | address.flat[1] | 24 | 20201228 | 23 | 20201123 |

I have tried with spark sql functions get_json_object() but it is not working. Any suggestion will be really helpful

Comment: what are the data types of name and address columns? StringType or StructType?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create another json column in order to use `get_json_object`... see my answer below.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df1.select(
    'id',
    'date',
    F.to_json(
        F.struct(
            F.from_json('name', 'fname string, lname string').alias('name'),
            F.from_json('address', 'lane string, flat array<string>, pin string').alias('address')
        )
    ).alias('jsoncol')
).join(
    df2.withColumnRenamed('date', 'date2'), 'id'
).withColumn(
    'new_value',
    F.expr("get_json_object(jsoncol, '$.' || changed_field)")
).groupBy('id', 'changed_field').agg(
    F.array_sort(
        F.collect_list(
            F.array('date', 'new_value')
        )
    ).alias('values')
).select(
    'id',
    'changed_field',
    F.col('values')[1][1].alias('new_value'),
    F.col('values')[1][0].alias('newdate'),
    F.col('values')[0][1].alias('old_value'),
    F.col('values')[0][0].alias('olddate')
)
```

```
result.show(truncate=False)
+---+---------------+------------+--------+---------+--------+
|id |changed_field  |new_value   |newdate |old_value|olddate |
+---+---------------+------------+--------+---------+--------+
|A1 |name.lname     |Bhattacharya|20201228|Bhatt    |20201128|
|A2 |address.flat[1]|24          |20201228|23       |20201123|
+---+---------------+------------+--------+---------+--------+
```